# Error after bundle install on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Every time i install a gem on production using bundle install i got this error

```
Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

Also i get the following warning when i do a bundle install

```
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
```

I tried removing the Gemfile.lock and re-installed the gems but it still not working

Thanks in advance.

Comment: output of `bundler -v` ?

Comment: Bundler version 1.7.9

Comment: did you make any research?

Comment: yes, i tried some options like --deployment and --without but it still not working

Comment: Please share your gemfile. Also, what is the platform, and the production environment? Try running `bundle install` (without `sudo`) to get rid of the warning.

Comment: I am not using sudo, OS is Ubuntu 14.04